# ClickOnce application working fine in IE and not in other browsers

Tags: c#, .net

ClickOnce application working fine in IE and not in other browsers as it's own 
they depends on some plug-in's. Can anybody give me suggestion or solution that it work in all browsers with out any plug-in's.

Comment: ClickOnce is only supported by IE... a basic google search would have told you that.

Comment: You need to install the appropriate plug-in for other browsers. There is no workaround.

Comment: I don't think there is a plugin for clickonce applications @MatthewWatson

Comment: @PatrickHofman Yes there is, we run our clickonce apps on Chrome and Firefox (in addition to IE), although I think the old Chrome plugin may be deprecated (but there's a new one https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/meta4-clickonce-launcher/jkncabbipkgbconhaajbapbhokpbgkdc?hl=en)

Comment: @matt didn't know that. Thanks for sharing. I do want to note it is non-official. That might be a drawback for companies.

Comment: @PatrickHofman True, but note that the Firefox one IS offical.

Answer (score 3):

This is from a question on another forum which describes your problem

> What's happening is that the .application file used for
>   ClickOnce contains a relative path to the manifest for the
>   application. Internet Explorer apparently launches the ClickOnce
>   engine passing it the original url, so the relative path works. Both
>   Firefox and Opera (didn't test other browsers yet) download the
>   .application file to some temp directory, then launch clickonce. Since
>   the manifest isn't in the temp directory, ClickOnce fails.
>   https://channel9.msdn.com/Forums/Coffeehouse/134875-ClickOnce-and-alternative-browsers

Scott Hanselman also has an interesting Blogpost about this topic (he couldnt manage to get click once to work with firefox)

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/PermaLink.aspx?guid=7ce42ccd-e531-4d43-a93f-73483c0afd3d

It seems like this is a bug (it has been reportet as a bug)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you mean that the `.vsto` or `.application` extensions don't work on other browsers than IE. Well, that is right since those browsers don't support it.

You should use the installer exe that comes with publishing a ClickOnce project. That will work on any browser.

Comment: Can you please give me details about the 'installer exe' so that i can work on....

Answer (score 0):

Today, it feels as though other browsers are able to "open" the .application files, they seem to run after.  Also, the 'installer exe' is usually named setup.exe, which will install dependencies and the application.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).